# RabbitMQ simulataneous transactions not happening

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, listener, spring-transactions

From my java(Spring boot) code I am calling two RabbitMQ events. But what is happening without completion of one event , the other event is getting started and getting completed and after that the first event is getting completed.Since, using both the events I am updating the same table, so, only one event's(listener) transactions is being committed and when i check in the database only one event(listener) changes i am able to see, the other event's(listener) changes I am not able to see. Not sure  of why this is happening and what could be the fix.

Comment: Is it possible changes from the second listener were overwritten by the first one? Or are you updating different columns / tables?

Comment: Table is same but columns are different

Comment: better if you can share the relevant code Snippet, are those two event being consumed by same consumer method?

Comment: @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue("update.product"), 
        exchange = @Exchange("event"), key = ProductNameUpdateEvent.NAME))
    public void updateProductName(@Header(AmqpHeaders.MESSAGE_ID) String messageId,
            GroupProductUpdateEvent event) {
        Product product = repositoryService.findById(Product.class, event.getProductId());
     product.setName("abc");  
    } This is the first listener updating name column of product table & second one is same just update quantity column of same table but both have to be different listeners cannot combine.